# Помогите составить регулярное выражение VC++13

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Нужно составить регулярное выражение для *HTML*-тега `<script>`.
Причем нужно **сохранить** все данные, которые указаны, как атрибуты внутри тега, так и сами данные между открывающимся и закрывающимся тегами.

То есть, например из такого кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/openapi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       VK.init({apiId: 3251711, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>
```

на выходе, после отработки регулярного выражения, должен получиться следующий ответ:

```
type="text/javascript" src="/openapi.js"
type="text/javascript"
VK.init({apiId: 3251711, onlyWidgets: true});
```

**Что получилось у меня:**

Я смог придумать только вот такую регулярку:

```
<\s*script\s*([^>]*)>\s*([^<]*)<\s*\/script\s*>
```

Она работает только в частных случаях, а именно в тех, где между тегами нет символа "<".
Вот результат ее работы:

[image: регулярное выражение]

Как видно, работает она только в частных случаях.

Огромная просьба помочь: сам я пока только новичок в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: А скажите, ножичек :), зачем там *символ "<" между тегами * ?

Comment: Ну вот если из большого скрипта убрать все сравнения > или < , то моя регулярка сработает, в ином случае она не работает.

Comment: она не сработает, в смысле захватит лишнего,? я не знаю, как у вас в си, но жадность регулярных выражений можно поменяь ключиком, тогда и `.+` должно сработать

Comment: Между тегами захват выражения берется следующей регуляркой: \s*([^<]*) , но так как внутри скрипта могут быть символы "<", то захват не произойдет

Comment: я про это и говорю, что сейчас если сделаь <script>.+</script>. то он захватит сразу все скрипты, а не жадный, не захватит

Comment: вот  https://www.regex101.com/r/zR2sD1/1 ключ U уберешь, увидишь разницу

Comment: не, так не работает.

Comment: @Виталий Вам предложили в Вашем примере заменить конструкцию \s*([^<]*) на .+, чтобы получилось <\s*script\s*([^>]*)>(.+)<\s*\/script\s*>

Comment: Ну вот в PHP это замечательно работает, https://www.regex101.com/r/zR2sD1/2 , но в с++ нельзя сделать php стиль регулярок, а уж тем более там модификаторов U и s нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю всех особенностей регулярок на C++, однако постараюсь помочь.

Вот регулярка PCRE:

```
~<\s*script\s*([^>]*)>(.*?)<\s*\/script\s*>~gs
```

~ границы регулярки (вам наверно не нужны). Конечные символы: g - чтобы выхватывал все совпадения (надо для regex101.com), s - чтобы символ `.`, обозначающий любой символ, учитывал и перевод строки - надо для многострочного текста.

Вот ссылка: https://www.regex101.com/r/zR2sD1/3
Вроде все работает.
Как видите я убрал ограничения на `<` и заменил на `(.*?)`. А именно тут `*?` значит повторять предыдущее выражение (`.` - любой символ) сколько угодно раз, но так мало, как это возможно (это все можно прочесть на regex101.com если навести курсов на нужную позицию в регулярке).

Такой же прием можно использовать и для атрибутов:

```
~<\s*script\s*(.*?)>(.*?)<\s*\/script\s*>~gs
```

Если будут еще вопросы задавайте.

UPD: Посмотрел регулярки в С++ : модификатор s соответсвует (?s), то есть ваша регулярка должна выглядеть как то так:

```
(?i)(?s)<\s*script\s*(.*?)>(.*?)<\s*\/script\s*>
```

То есть с самого начала включаем многострочный режим и не смотрим на регистр символом (за это отвечает (?i) ).
Тут так написано http://www.slideshare.net/bulgakovdmitriy/c-37604265

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, все сработало. В С++ можно установить PCRE стиль. Все нашлось.

Comment: @Виталий пожалуйста. Я еще дописал как отменить различие регистров, ведь можно написать <SCRIPT>, хотя тут уж на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге все получилось и ответ таков:

Надо использовать PCRE стиль регулярных выражений в с++ и использовать следующую регулярку с флагом 's':

```
<\s*script\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*(.*?)\s*<\s*\/script\s*>
```

Код на С++ выглядит следующим образом:

```
static const std::string regex_rule = "<\\s*script\\s*(.*?)\\s*>\\s*(.*?)\\s*<\\s*/script\\s*>";
static const boost::regex reg(regex_rule, boost::regex_constants::icase | boost::regex_constants::perl | boost::regex_constants::mod_s);

boost::cmatch result;
const char *first = &text[0];
const char *last = first + strlen(text);

boost::cregex_iterator it1(first, last, reg);
boost::cregex_iterator it1_end;

while (it1 != it1_end)
{
    cout << "\tНайдено совпадение: " << std::endl;
    result = *it1;
    if ((*it1)[1].length() != 0) cout << "\t\tИндекс 1: " << result.position(1) << ", длина: " << result.length(1) << std::endl;
    if ((*it1)[2].length() != 0) cout << "\t\tИндекс 2: " << result.position(2) << ", длина: " << result.length(2) << std::endl;
    ++it1;
}
```